# Making the powerset into a topological monoid

Tags: gn.general-topology, semigroups-and-monoids, topological-semigroups-and-monoids

Every monoid $X$ induces a monoid structure $\circledast$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ via
$$U\circledast V := \{uv\ |\ u\in U,v\in V\}.$$
Moreover, a morphism of monoids $f\colon X\to Y$ induces a morphism of monoids $f_*\colon\mathcal{P}(X)\to\mathcal{P}(Y)$ via the direct image.

Now, there are a couple of topologies we can put on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ making $\mathcal{P}(X)$ into a topological space and for which the continuity of $f$ implies the continuity of $f_*$, like the lower Vietoris, upper Vietoris, and Vietoris topologies on $\mathcal{P}(X)$.

Is it known whether the upper, lower, and Vietoris topologies also make $\mathcal{P}(X)$ into a topological monoid, i.e. such that $\circledast\colon\mathcal{P}(X)\times\mathcal{P}(X)\to\mathcal{P}(X)$ is continuous?

Comment: (P.S. Vietoris topologies are often defined only for subspaces of closed sets, but they also make sense for all of $\mathcal{P}(X)$; see e.g. section 1 of [Clementino–Tholen](http://topology.nipissingu.ca/tp/reprints/v22/tp22206.pdf))

Comment: Is $X$ assumed to carry a topology?  I've never actually heard this called Day convolution by any semigroup theorist.

Comment: My memory is that Carruth looked at this sort of thing and maybe you should look at his books with Hildebrant. The theory of topological semigroups.  I think they are called hyperspace semigroups.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Apologies for the name, Day convolution is definitely non-standard terminology; I've been using it for quite a while and ended up forgetting that it was non-standard when I wrote the question (which I've rewritten now).

Comment: And thanks for the reference for Carruth's work! I couldn't find a statement for all of $\mathcal{P}(X)$, but Theorem 3.1 of Carruth's second book with Hildebrant has a proof that the subspace $C(X)$ of closed subsets of a compact semigroup $X$ is also a compact semigroup (I'm not sure if their proof applies if one drops compactness and replaces $C(X)$ with $\mathcal{P}(X)$, though). (They also mention Carruth's master thesis and Hofmann–Mostert's _Elements of compact semigroups_ as sources that deal with this question, but I unfortunately don't have access to them)

Comment: (I've also removed the second question; the idea was to find a smallest/largest assignment of topologies $\{\text{topologies on $X$}\}\to\{\text{topologies on $\mathcal{P}(X)$}\}$ for each set $X$ such that $x\mapsto\{x\}$ is an embedding, $f$ continuous implies $f_*$ continuous, and $\circledast$ is continuous, but trying to make this precise ran into set-theoretic issues)

Comment: The real expert is @TarasBanakh so maybe he will chime in.

Comment: @Emily When X carries not just a topology but a uniform structure, a usually better behaved structure on P(X) is the hyperspace uniform structure. See e.g. "Uniform Spaces" by Isbell. This may or may not help, depending on your motivation for the question.

Comment: @user95282 Thanks! I do find this very helpful =) When I originally asked this question I was mainly interested in better understanding the various notions of "continuous" relations/multivalued functions, though now I'm just trying to understand powerset topologies and how behaved they are in general. Essentially I'm looking for an interesting topology in $\mathcal{P}(X)$ making the usual operations on powersets continuous and which behaves well with the topology on $X$, which I've asked about [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441087)